# Docker-compose hanging on pulling image where Dockerfile doesn't

Tags: node.js, docker, raspberry-pi, docker-compose, hypriot

I'm having an interesting problem... would love any tips, suggestions, or pointers in the right direction. Not sure where to start with this one, really.

Basically, we have a docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM hypriot/rpi-node:7

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/rrp-database
WORKDIR /usr/src/rrp-database

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/rrp-database
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/rrp-database
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
  image: hypriot/rpi-mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sqltest
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=rrplocal
  volumes:
    - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
    - 3306:3306

application:
  build: .
  working_dir: /opt/rrp/src/rrp-database
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
  links:
    - mysql
  command: bash -c "sleep 15 && node createTables.js && sleep 5 && node provisionDB.js && node server.js"
```

Most of this you don't need to delve in to, so he's there problem: when I run the setup via `docker-compose build`, our machine (a RaspPi, hence the hypriot versions) hangs completely when pulling the hypriot/rpi-node image.

```
$ docker-compose build
mysql uses an image, skipping
Building application
Step 1 : FROM hypriot/rpi-node:7
7: Pulling from hypriot/rpi-node
395823d8c49b: Extracting [====>                                              ] 4.129 MB/45.86 MBBnload complete
   298 B/298 BDownload complete
44f82080e2cc: Download complete
a3ed95caeb02: Download complete
f23aeb340745: Download complete
466adec6a1f2: Download complete
281ed5189bce: Download complete
95c0246ab315: Download complete
0a596801c90f: Downloading [=======================>                           ] 51.89 MB/111.9 MBnload complete
e1613bd476c1: Download complete
```

It stays like this forever, and hangs the machine. However, when running the Dockerfile alone - `docker build -t rrp-database .` (which I thought is essentially what the docker-compose is doing anyway...) the image pulls and builds without a hitch.

It's very much worth noting that this was tested on two separate machines, with the exact same result.

I'd really like to use docker-compose, but I'm not sure where to start with this issue. Any thoughts?

Much appreciation to anyone who has some answers for me! Cheers!

Comment: Output from `docker-compose --verbose up` might be helpful to diagnose.

Comment: Very true. Will try that on my next run, which I'm about to do - thanks :)